# Navigation bug with BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview

Navigation from my BottomNavigationView isn't working correctly and I'm stumped.

- When I first open the app, it works fine. I click a button in the BottomNavigationView and the corresponding fragment is displayed.
- I start seeing the bug after I navigate from fragment A to fragment B using a "go to B" button on fragment A. From then on, when I click the A button in the BottomNavigationView, B is displayed.

Things I've tried:

- I overrode all the fragment lifecycle callbacks in A (onCreate(), onCreateView(), onViewCreated(), onViewStateRestored(), onStart(), onResume()). I put breakpoints in each. None are hit when in the buggy state.
- I created a new app with the Android template for Bottom Navigation Activity, and reproduced the bug there. The only thing I changed was to add a button on fragment A that navigates to fragment B.

I'm new to both Android and stack overflow so let me know if I'm doing anything silly. Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's the code that reproduces the bug. (Fragment A is the HomeFragment)

HomeFragment.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.myapplication.R
import com.example.myapplication.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val textView: TextView = binding.textHome
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            textView.text = it
        }
        return root
    }

    // This is the code I added
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {view ->
            view.findNavController().navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.actionNavigationHomeToNavigationDashboard())
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- I added this button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dashboard"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_home"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

mobile_navigation.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <!-- I added this action -->
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_to_navigation_dashboard"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_dashboard" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications" />
</navigation>
```

MainActivity.kt (didn't modify this)

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml (didn't modify this)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Top level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

// I added everything within the buildscript block
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.1")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    // I added this line
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Oh, I'm having this problem right now... Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sadly not yet! I'll post if I do though.

Comment: I'm having the same issue!

Comment: guys, any solution yet?

Comment: Just came across this bug myself. I downgraded to nav library 2.3.5 and the issue disappeared. The issue still exists in 2.5.0-beta01

Comment: See the bug and details here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228201897

Comment: @TimB Oh, thanks for your sharing. 
I'm struggling with this issue. The fragment is destroy when navigating.
Do you have any sample can share ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The fix is to add the last three lines to the action tag in mobile_navigation.xml:

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_to_navigation_dashboard"
    app:destination="@id/navigation_dashboard"
    app:restoreState="true"
    app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_home"
    app:popUpToSaveState="true"
/>
```

More information about why this works: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/multi-back-stacks#nav-xml

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for a lot of solutions to this problem but none of them worked for me.
Finally, I have found a *lazy hack* that can "fix" this "bug". I have already tested this solution for a while and no issues have been found so far.

**Note: this is NOT an official way to fix this issue. I suggest NOT to use this solution UNTIL none of the solutions worked for you.**

**Solution:**

Replace this line:

```
navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_dashboard);
```

with this line:

```
findViewById(R.id.nav_view).findViewById(R.id.navigation_dashboard).performClick();
```

`R.id.nav_view` is the id of the `BottomNavigationView` component. It could be inside your *activity_main.xml*.
[image: id of the BottomNavigationView component]

`R.id.navigation_dashboard` is the id of the fragment that you want to navigate to. It could be inside your *res/navigation/mobile_navigation.xml*  or  *res/navigation/nav_graph.xml*.
[image: id of the fragment that you want to navigate to]